# Converting Console App to Form with Progress Bar?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, console-application

I've created a Console App which takes about 5 minutes to run. The main method calls around 10 methods that do the work.

How can I change the Console App to be a Windows Forms application that updates a progress bar/displays the latest progress through these 10 methods?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BackgroundWorker` component in Winforms. Just copy-paste this code. I have used a `Label instead of ProgressBar`.  The label is updated with the `percentage completion` as the task progresses in the Background.

The time - consuming method / task has to be called in the `Do_Work` handler. Run the sample below.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        BusinessClass _biz = new BusinessClass();
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitWorker();
        }

        private void InitWorker()
        {
            if (_worker != null)
            {
                _worker.Dispose();
            }

            _worker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
            _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
            _worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        /// Do the time consuming work here
        void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int highestPercentageReached = 0;
            if (_worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                double i = 0.0d;
                int junk = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= 199990000; i++)
                {
                    int result = _biz.MyFunction(junk);
                    junk++;

                    // Report progress as a percentage of the total task.
                    var percentComplete = (int)(i / 199990000 * 100);
                    if (percentComplete > highestPercentageReached)
                    {
                        highestPercentageReached = percentComplete;
                        // note I can pass the business class result also and display the same in the LABEL  
                        _worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete, result);
                        _worker.CancelAsync();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Display some message to the user that task has been
                // cancelled
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // Do something with the error
            }
        }

        void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text =  string.Format("Result {0}: Percent {1}",e.UserState, e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
    }

    public class BusinessClass
    {
        public int MyFunction(int input)
        {
            return input+10;
        }
    }
}
```